# How to Access an onBindViewHolder item Value from MainActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I have an OnbindViewHolder method in my `CarDetailsListAdapter.java` file like below

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CarDetailsListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    final CarDetailModel currentItem = getItem(i);

    Log.e("check", String.valueOf(modelItems));
    Log.e("check position", i+" "+currentItem.getCarIsSelected());


    // check car min is no cabs or not
    if(!currentItem.getCarMin().equals("No cabs")) {

        if (selectcar) {

            viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
            //selectedItem =viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
            selectcar = false;
        } else {

            viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
        }
    }

    // set default select car
    viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(selectedItem == i);

    if(first&&currentItem.getCarIsSelected())
    {
        viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
        first=false;
    }
    viewHolder.car_min.setText(currentItem.getCarMin());
    viewHolder.car_amount.setText(currentItem.getCarAmount());
```

Now I need to access above `viewHolder.car_amount` value from my MainActivity, i have no idea how to access this value

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you have position of required viewholder?

Comment: amount is updated based on selecteditem click

Answer (score 1):

You want to access car_amount but you have multiple cell in your recyclerview. I will suppose that you want to access it after an "onClick" on your cell.

You can give to your adapter a listener to call when a click is done on a specific cell.

```
public CarDetailsListAdapter(CarDetailsListListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CarDetailsListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
   viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v->{
      mListener.onClick(currentItem.getCarAmount());
   }
}
```

Your activity :

```
public CarDetailsListActivity extends Activity implements CarDetailsListListener {
   ...

   mAdapter = new CarDetailsListAdapter(this);

   @Override
   public void onClick(int carAmount){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: in my main_Activity can i access it directly without any click event ?

Comment: Your viewholder is one cell in a list of multiple cell, if you want to give your main activity carAmount of a specific cell, you must know which one. What do you want your user do ? When do you need the car amount ?

Comment: viewholder is updating the amount currentItem.getCarAmount( where currentItem is selected item

Comment: you can make a method getCarAmountOfSelectedViewHolded() in your adapter. This will return currentItem.getCarAmount() when you will call it.

Comment: can you give me an example code of getCarAmountOfSelectedViewHolded()  and line of code to call it

Comment: In your main activity :
int amount = mAdapter.getCarAmountOfSelectedViewHolded();

In your adapter : 

public void getCarAmountOfSelectedViewHolded(){
return getItem(selectedItem).getCarAmount();
}

This option without click event (as you asked), require that you know the selectedItem