# How to get ViewHolder Recycler ViewHolder Index

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recycler View dynamically generate view holders to fill the screen (plus some extras) then it recycles the generated view holders.

As you'll see in the code below, i intend to customize an Index View of the Recycler View.
Since the viewHolder is recycled, if i customize the viewHolder based on the index, it will be repeated for other indexes.

```
//... other RecyclerViewAdapter Code
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StringViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.string_txt_view.text = stringList[position]
    holder.index_txt_view.text = DecimalFormat("#,###.##").format(position + 1)
    if (selectedIndex.contains(position)) {
        holder.string_txt_view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        holder.index_txt_view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        holder.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        holder.string_txt_view.setTextSize(20f)
    } else {
        holder.string_txt_view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        holder.string_txt_view.setTextSize(16f)
        holder.index_txt_view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        holder.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
}
```

In order to prevent this, i have to use `if-else` in the bind view holder.
The else statement, resets the views to the default config if does it does not meet the condition.

I have performance concerns, because i am manually setting everything (that was already default) instead of being specific.

How can i get the index of the viewHolder so that my actions can be targeted.

Comment: I just replay to a similar problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371098/how-to-access-an-onbindviewholder-item-value-from-mainactivity-in-android/59371641#59371641

You can add a listener to your adapter that can be called from the currentViewHolder.

An other tips for performance : if you have to change one cell, you don't have to notify / update all cell, you can just call notifyItemChanged(position) 

(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))

Comment: Cause RecyclerView will reuse your item view so you must set it again in your `onBindViewHolder` method,you will encounter issue of view chaos if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

The `if (selectedIndex.contains(position)) {` is probably causing the performance issues you are facing since it's *O(n)* and it's being called everytime a row becomes visible. Instead of using `contains`, you can initialize a boolean array like this (which is still an ugly approach, but it should be faster) since it's *O(1)*:

```
boolean[] selectedIndex = new boolean[stringList.length];

// If selected set to true
selectedIndex[position] = true;

if (selectedIndex[position]) {
   // It's selected 
}
```

You can also add a `isSelected` boolean to the `stringList` elements instead instead of always querying the `selectedIndex` which is much better.

Comment: thank you for providing a more optimized way of checking.